# Android VideoView save RTSP stream

Tags: android, save, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm playing on my Android Nexus One some videos of a few cisco cameras using a VideoView. While this works fine, I'm unsure if it's possible to save the movie to a file.

I'm opening an URL like rtsp://192.168.1.22:554/live.sdp

How can I save it to the SDcard ? Handle it like a file maybe ... Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement/use library, your own RTSP client which will pipe the incoming RTP packets into a file.
if you want to also play the video stream you can then give the media player a local RTSP server address to your RTSP server and then pipe the same RTP packets to the media player as well.
If you need you can find an open source RTSP server/client [here](http://mobicents-media-server.blogspot.com/2009/09/mobicents-rtsp-stack-100bta1-released.html)